# How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried this

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

But I'm getting the error as

> Failed tests:   setUp(com.TEST): The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see [code here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) . The latest version can be downloaded from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

How can I make Chrome test the Selenium WebDriver test cases?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can tell, whether you have downloaded the selenium chrome driver from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list and added it to library in eclipse under "Add External Jars" before running your selenium-java code.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You need to download the executable driver from:
[ChromeDriver Download](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Then use the following before creating the driver object (already shown in the correct order):

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This was extracted from the most useful guide from the [ChromeDriver Documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

Comment: @aimbire: hey I am facing same problem. I did the same thing suggested by you but getting this error. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\selenimPRJarg1\chromedriver.exe" Am I missing something"?

Comment: You have to download Selenium Standalone Server from here http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/, and add the jar file as a dependency to your Java project.

Comment: where do you use/type this? System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: While this is technically correct, you really shouldn't be setting that environmental variable in code, it's the same as hard coding a path in your code.  The environmental variable should be set on the machine that you run the code on, allowing each machine to store the chrome driver executable in a unique place but have everything still work.

Answer (score 21):

Download the updated version of the Google Chrome driver from [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

Please read the release note as well [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt).

If the Chrome browser is updated, then you need to download the new Chrome driver from the above link, because it would be compatible with the new browser version.

```
public class chrome
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that's a cumbersome solution. I'd advise you to change this if it's what you use nowadays.

Comment: The download link is now out of date.

Comment: This Code is not working in Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)    . Please bro suggest new code . Till now it was working in older version less than 65.0.0 version

Answer (score 18):

You should download the chromeDriver in a folder, and add this folder in your PATH environment variable.

You'll have to restart your console to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) on a macOS machine, you can use the command:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver
```

It should work fine after that with no other configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the Chrome driver. You can install this package using [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This could be the one but the version on NuGet is too old: 2.10.0 dated Oct 13 2014

Comment: Outdated again on 23 March. Unable to use on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below code to run test cases in Chrome using Selenium WebDriver:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        // Telling the system where to find the Chrome driver
        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "E:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Open google.com
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        String html = webDriver.getPageSource();

        // Printing result here.
        System.out.println(html);

        webDriver.close();
        webDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the latest version of `chromedriver` [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).
Once downloaded, unzip it at the root of your Python installation, e.g., `C:/Program Files/Python-3.5`, and that's it.

You don't even need to specify the path anywhere and/or add `chromedriver` to your path or the like.
I just did it on a clean Python installation and that works.

Comment: bad advice... don't pollute your python installation

Comment: also, the OP never specified Python

Answer (score 4):

Download the latest version of the Chrome driver and use this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you can simply install the `chromium-chromedriver` package:

```
apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Be aware that this also installs an outdated Selenium version. To install the latest Selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are correct. Following is the little deep dive into the problem and solution.

The driver constructor in Selenium for example

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

searches for the driver executable, in this case the Google Chrome driver searches for a Chrome driver executable. In case the service is unable to find the executable, the exception is thrown.

This is where the exception comes from (note the check state method)

```
 /**
   *
   * @param exeName Name of the executable file to look for in PATH
   * @param exeProperty Name of a system property that specifies the path to the executable file
   * @param exeDocs The link to the driver documentation page
   * @param exeDownload The link to the driver download page
   *
   * @return The driver executable as a {@link File} object
   * @throws IllegalStateException If the executable not found or cannot be executed
   */
  protected static File findExecutable(
      String exeName,
      String exeProperty,
      String exeDocs,
      String exeDownload) {
    String defaultPath = new ExecutableFinder().find(exeName);
    String exePath = System.getProperty(exeProperty, defaultPath);
    checkState(exePath != null,
        "The path to the driver executable must be set by the %s system property;"
            + " for more information, see %s. "
            + "The latest version can be downloaded from %s",
            exeProperty, exeDocs, exeDownload);

    File exe = new File(exePath);
    checkExecutable(exe);
    return exe;
  }
```

The following is the check state method which throws the exception:

```
  /**
   * Ensures the truth of an expression involving the state of the calling instance, but not
   * involving any parameters to the calling method.
   *
   * <p>See {@link #checkState(boolean, String, Object...)} for details.
   */
  public static void checkState(
      boolean b,
      @Nullable String errorMessageTemplate,
      @Nullable Object p1,
      @Nullable Object p2,
      @Nullable Object p3) {
    if (!b) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(format(errorMessageTemplate, p1, p2, p3));
    }
  }
```

**SOLUTION**: set the system property before creating driver object as follows.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The following is the code snippet (for Chrome and Firefox) where the driver service searches for the driver executable:

**Chrome:**

```
   @Override
    protected File findDefaultExecutable() {
      return findExecutable("chromedriver", CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY,
          "https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver",
          "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html");
    }
```

**Firefox:**

```
@Override
 protected File findDefaultExecutable() {
      return findExecutable(
        "geckodriver", GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY,
        "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver",
        "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases");
    }
```

where CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY = "webdriver.chrome.driver"
and GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY = "webdriver.gecko.driver"

Similar is the case for other browsers, and the following is the snapshot of the list of the available browser implementation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome, follow these steps:

1. First of all, set the property and Chrome driver path:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
   ```
2. Initialize the Chrome Driver's object:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```
3. Pass the URL into the `get` method of WebDriver:

   ```
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I included the binary into my projects resources directory like so:

```
src\main\resources\chrome\chromedriver_win32.zip
src\main\resources\chrome\chromedriver_mac64.zip
src\main\resources\chrome\chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public WebDriver getWebDriver() throws IOException {
    File tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("chromedriver").toFile();
    tempDir.deleteOnExit();
    File chromeDriverExecutable;

    final String zipResource;
    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
        zipResource = "chromedriver_win32.zip";
    } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
        zipResource = "chromedriver_linux64.zip";
    } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
        zipResource = "chrome/chromedriver_mac64.zip";
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsuppoerted OS");
    }

    try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/chrome/" + zipResource)) {
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is)) {
            ZipEntry entry;
            entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            chromeDriverExecutable = new File(tempDir, entry.getName());
            chromeDriverExecutable.deleteOnExit();
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(chromeDriverExecutable)) {
                IOUtils.copy(zis, out);
            }
        }
    }

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverExecutable.getAbsolutePath());
    return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Download the EXE file of chromedriver and extract it in the current project location.

Here is the link, where we can download the latest version of chromedriver:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Here is the simple code for the launch browser and navigate to a URL.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://any_url.com");
```

Comment: Download the chromedriver and extract it. next create a folder in your project and name it as chromedriver and keep the .exe file in it. and use this path.  This is the simple code example. 'code'      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
  WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  searchbox.sendKeys("best selenium video tutorials free");
  searchbox.submit();

Comment: Please, considere updating this answer with the additional info vinay commented.