# Error: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying [node.js selenium web driver example](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs)...

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

... but got error

```
promise.js:1542
      throw error;
            ^
UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
    at new bot.Error (/Users/maks/Dropbox/nodeApps/orgi/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109:18)
```

I [guessed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13725255/1024794) to set PATH variable:

```
$ cat .bashrc

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/Dropbox/chromedriver
```

And restart console, but got the same error.

Comment: I had to use Firefox to get end to end tests to work on Linux using Protractor.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using selenium-server-standalone-***.jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list), you can pass `webdriver.chrome.driver` property when launching it like so:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\dev\chromedriver.exe"
```

This eliminates the error; Java command line option `-Dproperty=value` sets a system property value as expected.

Comment: don't you need to escape those back slashes?

Comment: @kajacx: the above syntax is correct for a "vanilla" command line launch

Comment: I know it is old post but this solution has been usefull for me after migrating from Behat 2 to Behat 3 which was complaining about chromedriver. +1

Answer (score 6):

Just in case some one getting this error :

> Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException:
>   Unknown option: -Dwebdrive

this **[thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2571)** might help :

Use Parameters before jar file

```
 java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)
```

So your command should be:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\dev\chromedriver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

Hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the selenium server but just want to use the chromedriver directly, something like this will work:

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(__dirname + '/node_modules/.bin/chromedriver').build();
var driver = new chrome.createDriver(capabilities, service);
```

It's not very well documented, I had to poke around the source code a bit.

Comment: How would you use this while still having the ability to use `chrome.Options()`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found is to make the chromedriver file executable.

Incorrect:

```
**-rw-rw-r--** 1 user user  5560736 Jul 31 00:56 chromedriver
```

Correct:

```
**-rwxrwxr-x** 1 user user 58204704 Aug 14 08:18 phantomjs
```

Once chromedriver matched phantomjs it sprang to life

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following code to set path in your code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your_path");
```

Path to be mentioned within quotes.