# selenium standalone server with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to run some test using selenium standalone server on Google Chrome but it runs Firefox instead when I execute this code:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="webdrive\chromedriver.exe" -jar ./selenium-server-2.42.2-withFarsi.jar -htmlSuite "*chrome" http://www.google.com C:\Users\...\TestSuit.html  temp.html
```

after this it runs Firefox and starts running test as usual.

What can I do?

Comment: Check this link out [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729517/4193730](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729517/4193730)

Comment: looks like a misspelling in "webdrive" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `*chrome` use `*googlechrome`.