# Selenium not starting portable chrome but local installation

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I have a problem with the Selenium web driver. What I'm trying to do is to start a "portable" chrome instead of my local installation, because it has different settings.

The problem is that the portable Chrome (from PortableApps) seems to only start when using GoogleChromePortable.exe. If I use the Chrome binary directly, it will start my local installation.
With Selenium it seems that no matter what Chrome path I pass to it (GoogleChromePortable.exe or binary path), it starts my local installation.

Here is my code:

```
String chromePath = "M:/my/path";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", chromePath);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Any ideas how to be able to start my portable chrome?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling upon this problem, here is how I managed to get the portable Chrome starting:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(binaryPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 and got Chrome Portable from PortableApps.com.

comments by @mario.schlipf and @SeJaPy were helpful, but I noticed that in the newer Webdriver releases, the *setbinary* method has been replaced by *binary_location*

This is how it actually worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromedriverpath='M:/my/chromedriver.exe'
chromePath = 'M:/my/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe'    #  <==  IMPORTANT! See note below.

chromeoptions = Options()
chromeoptions.add_argument('--incognito')
chromeoptions.binary_location = chromePath   

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriverpath, options=chromeoptions)
```

**NOTE:**

The *chromePath* variable must point to the Chrome executable in the portabilized environment.

In packages obtained from PortableApps.com, you have two executables: a *GoogleChromePortable.exe* in the install (actually, unpack) directory and a *chrome.exe* in *[installdirectory]/App/Chrome-bin*, the first being "just" a launcher which provides the portabilized app with a consistent environment.

As I could observe, chromedriver needs to directly interact with the "real" Chrome executable, otherwise the script will launch the browser (via the launcher) but will eventually crash with error message:

`unknown error: DevTools Active Port file doesn't exist`

and no browser session will be returned as a result.

This may seem obvious to many people... but it was not to me, so I decided to put this note in order to make some clarity for the less clever guys (myself included) :).

Comment: Thanks.  `[installdirectory]/App/Chrome-bin` was helpful and resolved my issue.  I was just referencing `GoogleChromePortable.exe`, which produced an error:  [Failed to load extension... Manifest file is missing or unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b3bx.jpg), even though I wasn't loading any extensions.

Answer (score 2):

```
  String chromePath = "M:/my/googlechromeporatble.exe path"; 
  String chromedriverpath="M:/my/chromedriver.exe path";
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setBinary(chromepath);
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromedriverpath);              
  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This will invoke portable chrome rather than local installation.
First set google chrome portable path and then invoke chromeriver.exe

Comment: Does any one know that this portable chrome is working on Azure or not? Has anyone tried?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the settings you have in ChromePortable, maybe you could default ChromeDriver with [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)?

I'm thinking especially on `custom profile`. If you somehow could get that from your ChromePortable and load it with default ChromeDriver?

EDIT: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome) could help