# How to configure env.rb to start portable chrome (instead of local installation) with Ruby, Selenium and LapisLazuli

Tags: ruby, localhost, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, portable-applications

**Question**:

For my Test Automation Suite I would like to know how to configure/setup my portable Chrome to run instead of the local installed Chrome.

**Reason**:

There is an issue with the application I'm trying to test and Chrome Version 55. Issue: Certain buttons are since this version not clickable and I want to bypass this for the time being by using an older Chrome version.

I use Ruby version 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290)
And LapisLazuli as described on www.testautomation.info
The setup itself is working. The answer might be simple, but I did not manage to get this running in this combination.
I found information about selenium/Java, but I have no idea how to get that to work with my setup.
[Selenium not starting portable chrome but local installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817962/selenium-not-starting-portable-chrome-but-local-installation)
I also found this website: https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read
And here they mentioned the following:

`3 > require "selenium-webdriver"
4 => true
5 
6 > Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path =
7 'C:\chrome\chrome.exe'
8 => "C:\\chrome\\chrome.exe"`

So I tried that in irb and this worked

`require 'lapis_lazuli'
 include LapisLazuli
 Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\chrome_portable_v53\chrome.exe'
 browser :chrome`

The portable chrome version was started. Now I only need to know how to place this in my env.rb file (I assume), which looks currently like this:

`require 'lapis_lazuli'
 require 'lapis_lazuli/cucumber'
 LapisLazuli::WorldModule::Config.config_file = "config/config.yml"
 World(LapisLazuli)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is answering the question. I've added require selenium-webdriver and that Chrome.path to the env.rb and this seems to work.

```
require 'lapis_lazuli'
require 'lapis_lazuli/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\chrome_portable_v53\chrome.exe'
LapisLazuli::WorldModule::Config.config_file = "config/config.yml"

World(LapisLazuli)
```