# How do I install ChromeDriver on Windows 10 and run Selenium tests with Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We have an Ubuntu server which we use for running Selenium tests with Chrome and Firefox (I installed ChromeDriver) and I also want to run the tests locally on my Windows 10 computer. I want to keep the Python code the same for both computers. But I didn't find out how to install the ChromeDriver on Windows 10? I didn't find it on the documentation [[1](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), [2]](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver).

Here is the code that runs the test in Chrome:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class BaseSeleniumTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

    def start_selenium_webdriver(self, chrome_options=None):
        ...
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        ...
```

I also found [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome) but it seems to be not in Python (no programming language is tagged, what is it?)

**Update #1:** I found some Python code in https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started, but where do I put the file in Windows 10 if I want to keep the same Python code for both computers?

**Update #2:** I downloaded and put `chromedriver.exe` in `C:\Windows` and it works, but I didn't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: Is this still working for you after the latest Chrome updates? My test browser now comes up empty next to a small Command Prompt window.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, it works.

Comment: This site really helped me  https://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/classes/selenium/selenium-windows-install/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As Uri stated in the question, under **Update #2**, downloading the latest release of chromedriver and placing it in C:\Windows corrects the issue.

I had the same issue with Chrome hanging when the browser window opens (alongside a command prompt window).

The latest drivers can be found at:

https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver

The version in the chromedriver_win32.zip file is working on my 64-bit system.

Comment: New link of latest drivers  https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the `chromedriver.exe` and save it to a desired location
2. Specify the `executable_path` to its saved path

The sample code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("example.html")
# do something here...
driver.close()
```

As Uri stated in Update #2 of the question, if we put the `chromedriver.exe` under `C:/Windows`, then there is no need to specify `executable_path` since Python will search under `C:/Windows`.

Answer (score 5):

Let me brief out the requirements first.
You need to download the chrome web driver zip from here. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/

Extract the file and store it in a desired location.

Create a new project in Eclipse and include the following code in your class.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Explanation : `System.setProperty(key,value)`:

Key is default and same for all the systems, value is the location of your chromedriver extract file.