# Browser not opening using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Here is the error:

> [11762:11762:0801/141204:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url
>   pattern: chrome://print/*
>       getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE) failed
>       [11762:11886:0801/141205:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(243)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
>       getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE) failed

Code :

```
public class FirstTestCase { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome"); 
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
   String URL = "mail.google.com";;
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: public class FirstTestCase  {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  String URL = "https://mail.google.com";

Comment: [Selenium-Chrome setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome) This might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are two problem in your provided code :-

- You are setting `webdriver.chrome.driver` with installed chrome location which **wrong**. you need to download latest chrome driver `zip` from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and put at any location in your machine and extract that `zip` and set found `chromedriver` to the system property with variable `webdriver.chrome.driver`.
- You are providing wrong URL to launch, You should provide URL with `http://` or `https://`.

So the working example are as below :-

```
public class FirstTestCase { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/downloaded chromedriver"); 
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
   String URL = "https://www.google.com";
   driver.get(URL);
  }
}
```

Hope it works..:)

Comment: @muthubala is there any exception??

Comment: The driver executable is a directory

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: /home/administrator/Desktop @ Saurabh Gaur

Comment: @muthubala did you download latest chrome driver from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.22/..

Comment: Yes 2.22 @ Saurabh Gaur

Comment: @muthubala if in your system you are putting the `chromedriver.exe` at `/home/administrator/Desktop` location then use as : `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "home/administrator/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");`.. means provide `chromedriver.exe` with path as well

Comment: the same code without chromedriver.exe is showing the same error