# How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I need to create simple autotest using ChromeDriver with Maven.

excerpt from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

test case:

```
@BeforeTest
public void StartBrowser_NavURL() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterTest
public void CloseBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testToCompareDoubles() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

And after running test executing command

```
mvn -test
```

I receive the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at com.testTask.GoogleTest.StartBrowser_NavURL(GoogleTest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
... Removed 23 stack frames

I've read discussion accesible via the link below:
[How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)

But I can't download executables on my server. So, it's not an option for me.
But Maven downloads "selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.1.jar" on the server (which is OK for me).

Is there a way to use dowloaded .jar file instead of executable?

P.S. For this project I use IntelliJ Idea Community Edition and I'm not an expert with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer in the thrown exception. Just set the path to the executable chrome driver before initializing your driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to your chrome driver executable")
```

You can download chrome driver executable from the below link and put it to desired location:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Edited:

If you don't want to download the chrome driver manually then add dependency like this.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This will download the latest version of driver and set the proper java system variable using the command:

```
ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
```

Comment: Once more: I have NO permissions to download executables.

Comment: What does that mean? You need to have executable  chrome driver to run tests on chrome.

Comment: Your advice works: my tests are executed after downloading "chromedriver.exe". But all this stuff is supposed to be run with a single Maven command (e.g.: mvn -test). And I don't know, could Maven download files from the internet or not. So, I'm looking for a solution, which will minimise the quantity of downloaded external files. Otherwise, I should go to stakeholders to renegotiating.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

First download chromedriver.exe file and make sure it is compatible with Selenium Webdriver version.

then you have to setup the path using System.Setproperty as shown in below code

```
@BeforeTest
public void StartBrowser_NavURL() {
//setup the chromedriver path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to your chrome driver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

After this you need configure maven Surefire plugin in order to run maven project through command line.

Link : https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/