# Django - Lettuce - Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, firefox, lettuce

I'm trying to run default project with the above stack, to be able to run front-end tests on my big project. Which uses a much bigger stack. (I've been trying to integrate it for that first but after multiple failures I tried to recreate it in a default django app)

So the main issue is that Firefox throws Connection was reset error.
I've tried firefox versions: 45, 46, 47. With selenium 2.48 and 2.53.6. Nothing seemed to make it work.
I'm really unsure if it is related to that at all.

zero.feature:

```
Feature: Opening Page

  Scenario: Opening Landing page
    Given I access url "/"
```

zero.py

```
from lettuce import *
from selenium import webdriver


@step(r'I access url "(.*)"')
def access_url(step, url):
    world.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    world.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
```

and I have `lettuce.django` in INSTALLED_APPS. And it seems to run fine:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Django's builtin server is running at 0.0.0.0:8000

Feature: Opening Page                  # \blog\features\zero.feature:1

  Scenario: Opening Landing page       # \blog\features\zero.feature:3
    Given I access url "/"             # \blog\features\zero.py:7
what?
No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"
    Given I access url "/"             # \blog\features\zero.py:7

1 feature (1 passed)
1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)

Test Suite Summary:
1 feature (1 passed)
1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

So it does run lettuce and passes tests (well, nothing to fail). The issue is that the Firefox window that opens does not load anything at all with that error.

I tried Splinter also, which did the same thing with nicer syntax. I know that the above code is bad on many levels, but I had to reduce the errors that could create that issue. But no luck there.

Anyone met this issue with a resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled my computer, and now it seems to work. Must have been something system error. I've noticed that the url also changed, when it didn't work FF tried to open 0.0.0.0:8000, which also could have been an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what could be an issue - probably something with firefox browser.

Why dont you give chrome driver a try instead of firefox:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729517/5056023
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

And then see what happens. Selenium sometimes is moody, and no one knows why (crash when it generally should not crash).