# Invalid ZIP archive chromedriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver, executable-jar

I'm using eclipse 4.2 juno ver 8.0 and i tried to add chromedriver.exe in my java application. but its showing error `Invalid ZIP archive chromedriver.exe (org.eclipse.jdt.code)` in Error Log.
I did like this MyProject --> right click & buildpath --> configure build path --> add libraries & Add Jars. I've selected the chromedriver.exe from workspace and clicked OK.
After that i tried to execute the java file, run as Java Application but its showing error `Error: Could not find or load main packagename.classname` in console.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)