# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get an error while running this selenium script. Please suggest what can be done to fix this:
Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import csv
import time
driver = webdriver.chrome("<webdriver path>")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Search"]')
send_keys('abc')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="sbico _wtf _Qtf"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a')
print(var)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test2.py", line 2, in 
>       from selenium import webdriver
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I have installed Python 3.6 on win 7 Professional 32 bit. I have Selenium Standalone Server version 3.4.0([link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/))

Comment: have you installed selenium ? like pip install selenium?

Comment: I have Selenium Standalone Server version 3.4.0(link). I've also installed ChromeDriver 2.29. Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: the problem is the selenium file is not being loaded. go to cmd and use pip install selenium.

Comment: i'll try that today, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try installing selenium using pip. Use the following command.

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: Thanks, the above issue is fixed, but i get another error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome("<webdriver path>")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: You need to Download chrome Driver. check the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome

Comment: Your command with the -m and -U worked for me. It didn't work without those flags.

Comment: Could someone explain why this works? It seems not everyone needs to run it like this for it to work, but others do.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you have not run the installation command for webdriver_manager.

Use the following command:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

But before this, make sure you have properly installed selenium as well. If not, use the following command to install selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 4):

## Remarks to virtual environments

### virtualenv

If you are using a virtual environment like virtualenv. 
You have to make sure that the module selenium is installed 
1.) in the virtual environment and 
2.) in the default settings (when the virtual environment is deactivated).

Otherwise you will get the error message: 
 **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'**

### Example

Install selenium in the default settings: `pip install selenium`

Create virtual environment (on windows): `py -m virtualenv folder_env`

Activate virtual environment (on windows): `source folder_env/Scripts/activate`

Check virtual environment settings: `which python` and `which pip`

Install selenium: `pip install selenium`

Check pip list for selenium: `pip list`

(Optional) Exit virtual environment: `deactivate folder_env`

#### Miscellaneous

Virtualenv by Corey Schafer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk 
virtualenv is not a native module, you have to install it with
`pip install virtualenv`

Comment: Ok in my case I did all the above and tried the 'pip install selenium' and still had trouble.  Once I DEACTIVATED 'source deactivate' and then 'source activate' to refresh the virtual environment, I navigated back to my "tests" folder and ran 'pytest' just to run all the tests and BOOM! it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> driver = webdriver.chrome("")

there is no such class ^^.  It is named `webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the Quick and Easy Solution is to Go to Your Python Version Location, Then Libs, and then Site-packages.

***ex -* 
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages**

```
Try Deleting and Reinstalling Selenium, and Try Running the Code.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can enter these commands "pip install webdriver_manager"
2. Then "pip install selenium"

Answer (score 0):

## If Webdriver Manager is not installed, open CMD -> Type "pip install webdriver_manager" and enter.

If you found such an issue, then in Pycharm specific application:

1. Find path where your Python library exists. (Like C:\Users\cp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages)
2. Copy site-packages folder.
3. Go to Project.
4. Find "Lib" folder.
5. Expand Lib folder and you will find site_packages over there.
6. Paste site-packages.

I believe it will help you out.

Comment: 3. Go to Project in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it is worth mentioning.

Working on **`VSCode`** under **`Windows`** and I had this issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`, none of the solutions worked for me.

Finally, I figured out  that **`Python`** was installed twice:

- From the Windows store which will reside under : *`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Python`*
- Normal Install (i.e. download and install in a chosen directory, mine was *`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`*)

What drove me crazy was when I open the terminal and run :

> pip list

I found the selenium there, and it keeps telling me on the other hand : `No module named 'selenium'`

And it appears that **`VsCode`** launcher (*button to execute my .py file*) was bound, somehow, to the former location (the one downloaded from the store) while its terminal was linked to the latter one, so I uninstall it (the one from Windows Store) and selected the proper location of Python in the launcher's config in **`VsCode`** and it worked.