# I'm getting this exception on Windows OS and Chrome browser version: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at Demo.TestFacebookRegistration.main(TestFacebookRegistration.java:12)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set system properties where the chrome driver is located.

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","location_of_driver");
```