# Protractor with Visual Studio Team Services - "Could not find chrome binary"

Tags: selenium, protractor, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to setup **Protractor** on **Visual Studio Team Services** and currently I'm having a build run a `.bat` file to start my protractor test.

When the build runs, it gives me an error message saying `Could not find Chrome binary`, and gives me a file location that doesn't exist on my directory.

**Error trace-back:**

```
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z ##[section]Starting: Run script protractor.bat
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z
===========================================================================
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z Task         : Batch Script
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z Description  : Run a windows cmd or bat script and optionally allow it to change the environment
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z Version      : 1.1.3
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z Help         : [More Information]
(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613733)
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3521640Z     
============================================================================
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3601629Z ##[command]d:\a\1\s\protractor.bat 
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3761643Z 
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3761643Z d:\a\1\s>cd .\e2e 
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3761643Z 
2017-05-25T20:43:49.3761643Z d:\a\1\s\E2E>protractor conf.js 
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8302366Z [20:43:50] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z [20:43:50] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z [20:43:50] E/direct - Error code: 135
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z [20:43:50] E/direct - Error message: Could not find chromedriver at C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.25.exe
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z [20:43:50] E/direct - Error: Could not find chromedriver at C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.25.exe
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:65:27)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at Runner.createBrowser (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:197:43)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:276:30
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at _fulfilled (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at runSingle (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at flush (C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8342360Z [20:43:50] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8552361Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 135.
2017-05-25T20:43:50.8582364Z ##[section]Finishing: Run script protractor.bat
```

When I install Chromedriver on the build it installs it to a different file location: 
`d:\a\1\s\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe`

The test runs fine locally but doesn't work when I commit it to VSTS.

Is there anyway to make it so that `chromedriver` is installed in a different file location, or have Selenium look in a different place for `chromedriver`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Put the relative path to the ChromeDriver executable in `conf.js`. This is [well-documented](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts).

Comment: I tried that - got another error message:  `E/launcher - Error: spawn C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver ENOENT`

Answer (score 0):

Use `webdriver-manager` package that comes with `protractor` - it can download any version of any binary that you want - https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager

So it ends up with running `webdriver-manager update` before starting protractor tests (just make sure that if you are running locally installed protractor - you also update using locally installed webdriver-manager)

Answer (score 0):

First, based on the log, you are using Hosted Build agent that running as service, but the test need to be interact with UI, so you **can’t** to do Protractor test with Chrome on Hosted Build agent.

You can refer to this way to set up a private build agent on your machine: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Secondly, you can refer to these steps to install chromedriver:

1. Add Npm task (npm command: `install`; arguments: `-g protractor`)
2. Add Command Line task (Tool: `webdriver-manager`; Arguments: `update --versions.chrome 2.25`)