# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code:

```
package Basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class invokegoogle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sravani\\Desktop.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://qaclickacademy.com");

    }

}
```

Getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at Basics.invokegoogle.main(invokegoogle.java:12)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the `chromedriver.exe` is stored at your desktop, you need to make a couple of changes as follows:

- You need to replace the uppercase `W` with lower case **`w`** within `Webdriver.chrome.driver`.
- As you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system, presuming `chromedriver.exe` is placed in your desktop ypu need to append the *WebDriver* variant name along with the extension within the *absolute path* of the *WebDriver*.
- Effectively the line of code will be:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sravani\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```

> **Note**: `webdriver.chrome.driver` needs to start with lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Once you download chrome driver into your system, after extracting it (unzipping it) into the folder, it looks like you have directly copied the folder path "Downloads/chromedriver_win32.exe", instead using full path as below mentioned

Open the folder (chromedriver_win32.exe), then you will see "chromedriver.exe" as .exe file, and use this path instead and it looks like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

**Add your chrome driver to java resource folder**

[image: Driver location]

**Add the below mentioned code will work**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("drivers/chromedriver.exe")).getFile() );
```

Answer (score 0):

i also got same issue then searched so many answer and apply into my code but result showing null
then after i realized that i had declare static variable on above of class
looks like

```
private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

then i rewrite code on under void main class like

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

now my code running works fine 
you can also try like this or let me know so i can help you.