# Got Error message " The Path to the driver executable must set by the webdriver"

Tags: selenium

I am getting the below error when I call chrome browser using chrome driver. The error is :

[image: error screenshot]

> the path to the driver executable must set by the webdriver

I am using:

- Chrome 63
- chromedriver 2.34
- Selenium 3.8.1 (java)
- Java 8

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in it. 
 do not use images of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Don't summarize the error message... copy and paste it in full. Google the error message. You will find your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to invoke Google browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/unable-to-invoke-google-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the case. The system property value should have only small characters, like so:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe");
```