# java selenium Illegal Exception

Tags: java, selenium

I have added my chrome driver path in my system variable but still am getting the illegal exception , when i run my selenium script as :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Post your code and error stacktrace

Comment: you need to provide more information about the details such as exception and your development environment.

Comment: You should set this before creating driver object System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver");

Comment: WebDriver driver;
 @Test(dataProvider="MGM")
 public void MgmLogin(String Username,String Password) {
   //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe" );
   driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to invoke Google browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/unable-to-invoke-google-browser)

Comment: error : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)

Comment: Did you restart your IDE after adding ChromeDriver to your path?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have entered the wrong driver path.

Make sure to exclude the `chromedriver.exe` from your path variable.

[image]

To verify, open the Command Line (Run cmd.exe) -> Type chromedriver ->Hit Enter -> ChromeDriver

[image]

**After setting the path make sure to restart your IDE.**

Comment: i just need to execute without giving the System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of chromedriver");- i have given my chrome driver path in system variable

Comment: @karthick then try to put this in variable path

Comment: i did the same but still am getting the illegal exception

Comment: @karthick Did you add semicolon just before adding your chromedriver path? open your cmd and type ChromeDriver and hit enter just to verify

Comment: @karthick  check my latest answer