# Gecko driver issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

am unable to open browser using geckodriver 3.8.1 and selenium oxygen  and firefox 57.0.4(32 bit) version

```
package Selenium_JavaFundamentals;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class opengmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>       at Selenium_JavaFundamentals.opengmail.main(opengmail.java:10)

Please note that I have loaded the gecko driver.

Comment: You have to set the path to your driver Check this -- > http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/

Comment: "Please note that I have loaded the gecko driver." How? Where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to invoke Google browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/unable-to-invoke-google-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell it where the WebDriver is.
Like this:

```
package Selenium_JavaFundamentals;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



    public class opengmail {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckoDriver.exe");"
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        }    
}
```

Comment: This won't work as well. You need to first `System.setProperty()` next `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

From some research, I came across that

> WebDriver uses native browser approach. Selenium offers inbuilt driver
>   for Firefox but not for other browsers. All drivers (Chrome Driver, IE
>   driver, etc.) are built based on the special JS Engine used by each
>   browser.

So I suppose

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/path/to/geckoDriver.exe");"
```

isn't required for Firefox after all.

What seems to be the issue here is broken Firefox installation in your machine. Scrub your current installation completely and do a fresh install of the compatible Firefox. (Optional- Also you can put the Firefox.exe path in your PATH in Environment Variables.)

Comment: Your research is no longer correct. At some point in the past a separate driver was introduced and is now required even from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, i simply downgraded my firefox browser version- 43 this issue got resolved after downgrading the browser

Answer (score 0):

Set the geckodriver.exe location first before initializing the FirefoxDriver.

> For selenium 3.x with Firefox

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path.to.geckodriver.exe");  
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```