# Error :"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property" is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Following is my code snippet :

```
public class FindAllElementsFromTable {
    WebDriver  driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

and some tests after this.

When executed,getting above exception.
I tried with forward slash i.e. "C:/Selenium Drivers/chromedriver.exe" as well, but it makes no difference. I checked other answers, but I haven't made any of those mistakes like initialising the chromedriver twice/wrong place/setting property after WebDriver initialization/wrong driver name etc.
Can you help me understanding the exact issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to invoke Google browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/unable-to-invoke-google-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `setProperty` line.

It should be `webdriver` not `Webdriver`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
```