# Selenium:-java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium

I have made the Java Selenium Maven Project for printing all the data of the rows as well as header.The code worked fine but when i used the project on different system then i got the following error:-

`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` `The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`

I don't think that i need to set path for the jar in the maven project. Where i am missing ?

**Note:-** The code worked fine in the other system.
       The problem is not only with this code , approximately all the Selenium Maven project which i imported from other system is not working.

More Info:- **There is no error in properties->java build path**

```html
package com.xxx.webTableTest;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class WebTableTest {

 WebDriver driver;
 Logger logger;

 @BeforeTest
 public void setUp() {

  logger = Logger.getLogger(WebTableTest.class);
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/table-pagination-demo.html");
  logger.info("navigated to the test website for the webtable");
 }

 @Test
 public void testRadioButton() {

  List<WebElement> header = driver.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
  logger.info("Printing all the table headers");

  for (WebElement webElement : header) {
   System.out.println(webElement.getText());
  }
  List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

  logger.info("Printing all the table rows");

  for (WebElement webElement : rows) {
   System.out.println(webElement.getText());
  }
 }

 @AfterTest
 public void tearDown() {

  driver.quit();
 }

}

-------------------------------
POM.xml file

--------------------------------  

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Sapient</groupId>
  <artifactId>page-object-model-v2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>


-----------------
TestNG Run result
-----------------

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
 at com.sapient.webTableTest.WebTableTest.setUp(WebTableTest.java:23)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest tearDown
SKIPPED: testRadioButton
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
 at com.sapient.webTableTest.WebTableTest.setUp(WebTableTest.java:23)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

strong text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-b)

Comment: About your question: You do not have `chromedriver` in your maven. In Maven you have a `.jar` file which is a library to use in Java. But you also need an `.exe` file to RUN chromedriver.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski you are right, thats was where my concept was wrong, i understood it finally..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set path to your `chromedriver.exe` file.

Something like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Or you can set location of your `chromedriver.exe` file in your path in system environments. 
But in both cases you need to have chromedriver.exe file stored somewhere on your system.

EDIT: Since it works on your work machine you probably have folder which contains your .exe file added in your system environment path variable. Compare those two variables (your home and work machine) to be sure.

Check [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) for more details.

Comment: Why is there any need to add the path of jar if it is already there in the maven dependency ?I have checked the code it was working fine in my work machine but after importing it to my home machine it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can i kow which exe file you are talking about ?

Comment: acikojevic , driver for chrome is already there in the maven dependency

Comment: Follow the link I gave you and set it in your system path variable.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. Please upvote and mark answer as accepted so others could benefit from it. You can see contacts in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download chrome driver
2. make a driver folder alongside your project folder
3. placed chrome driver in driver folder
4. Add this code in your setup method

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
   WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply Kuldeep, why is there any need to add the path of jar if it is already there in the maven dependency ?I have checked the code it was working fine in my work machine but after importing it to my home machine it is not working.

Comment: Did you add <systemPropertyVariables>
            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
        </systemPropertyVariables>

Comment: Selenium requires more than just a maven <dependency>