# Selenium script not working Exception

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I am beginner to selenium and need some help with below script where I am trying to send value vai text field.
Below is the code snippet.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class login {
    static
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.com/authentication/login");

        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys("ravi");

    }

}
```

Shows error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>       at login.main(login.java:14)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587942/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
public class login {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Path/to/your/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 
 driver.get("https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.com/authentication/login");
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.name("login"))));
 driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys("ravi");
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: there are some version compability issue i think between ChromeDriver and chrome browser and selenium version so can you tell me exact which versions of chrome browser and chromedriver and selenium its working fine?i am using window 10

Comment: Selenium 3.11.0 and chrome driver version : 2.36 and chrome browser version 67.0

Comment: I am using Win 7 Pro