# Webdriver cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below are the versions i used.

Java 11.0
Selenium webdriver 3.14

Can anyone please let me know the solution for this.

```
package packageone;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class Firstclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver= new chromedriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the selenium library and any other necessary dependencies correctly?

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. Note the correct capitalisation of `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? _Eclipse_?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Firstclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Differences:

Line 2 - added import for `ChromeDriver` (your IDE should suggest you)

Line 7 - added path to crhrome driver; **Don't forget to replace** "/path/to/chromedriver" with a real FULL path to executable of crhomeDriver

Line 8 - `new chromeDriver()` ---> `new ChromeDriver()`;

[Ready examples of starting chromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome/13729517)