# com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java) with ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to simply start the chrome driver but getting some timeout errors. the browser does start but then closed after few sec with the following exception:

System info:

```
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'MAC-images-MacBook-Pro-1164.local', ip: '----', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver] with root cause
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
~[na:1.8.0_172]     at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
~[guava-25.0-jre.jar:na]    at
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar:na]     at
com.example.tests.bl.impl.AutomationRunner.run(AutomationRunner.java:29)
~[classes/:na]
```

Code snip:

```
@Component
public class AutomationRunner implements IAutomationRunner {



    @Override
    public void run() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Packages been used :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
 </dependency>
```

Any idea on what do I miss here? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'MAC-images-MacBook-Pro-1164.local', ip: '----', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
.
com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
~[guava-25.0-jre.jar:na]    at
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is within the `System.setProperty()` line where you have passed the *absolute path* of the *Google Chrome* binary instead of ***ChromeDriver*** binary.

---

### Solution

You need to download the relevant *ChromeDriver* binary for **Mac OS X** i.e. [**chromedriver_mac64**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/) and place it anywhere within your system, extract the *ChromeDriver* binary and pass the *absolute path* within the `System.setProperty()` as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. There is another solution for this.

Selenium requires Guava. Add below dependency as maven dependency to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631425/6491408